# In Presto SQL, for string column, how to remove text starting from a pattern in each string?

Tags: sql, regex, presto, trino

I'm trying to do some string cleanup and wanted to keep only the part that's before a given pattern and remove everything including the pattern and everything after. The pattern is 'hi {{user_name}}'. For example:

Input: What a good day. hi {{user_name}} how are you

Expected output: What a good day.

Input: What a good day. hi {{user_name}} let me know how I can help.

Expected output: What a good day.

Input: What a great day!

Expected output: What a great day!

I tried to do split by pattern and keep only the first part of the split result, but wasn't able to find a good way in SQL

Comment: is "user_name" a text constant, or it is a placeholder so the actual values might be for example `What a good day. hi {{john}} how are you`? Also, is "hi" a constant, or is the text to be removed better defined as "any sentence with `{{user_name}}` in it"? Your examples aren't different enough to be helpful - please provide more examples with more variations to clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using `regex_replace` with `hi {{user_name}}.*` pattern (explanation at [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/8eZ6wc/1)):

```sql
-- sample data
with dataset(str) as(
    values
        ('What a good day. hi {{user_name}} how are you'),
        ('What a good day. hi {{user_name}} let me know how I can help.'),
        ('What a great day!')

)

-- query 
SELECT regexp_replace(str, 'hi {{user_name}}.*', '')
FROM dataset;
```

Output (note that this will keep the space at the end):

| _col0 |
| --- |
| What a good day. |
| What a good day. |
| What a great day! |